# ASP.NET CORE 5 - AD Authentication

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I would like to build a web site that will allow any customer to login using their Azure AD. How can I do that? I have used previously authentication with Azure AD for my organization but how can I enable that for any customer? Sort of allowing customers to login with Facebook or Google, instead, when they click login they will be redirect to Azure AD.

Comment: I believe you will need to use Azure AD B2C to enable social logins.

Comment: According to my understanding, you want to develop a multiple-tenant application. Right? If so, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant

Comment: if you plan to allow users to register using social medias, Azure AD B2C is what you're looking for (as previous comment), if you want to allow customers to user their business accounts, Azure AD B2B

Comment: I don't think is a multitenant application. If you build a .net app and want users to login with facebook, you go to facebook create an app, add clientid and secret and then app users can login with facebook. I want to do the same but using Azure AD, where users can login with their respective Azure AD credentials from their own AD tenant.

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you, you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it to end the thread, thanks！

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a personal account or social account to log in to the Azure AD application, you only need to modify the manifest configuration of the existing application, and then change the `/tenant id` endpoint to the [`/common` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols#endpoints).

To change the setting for an existing AD App, navigate to the **Manifest** blade of it in the portal, find the [signInAudience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#signinaudience-attribute) attribute, set it with `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount` or `PersonalMicrosoftAccount`.

[image]